# Is it possible to select the input microphone on Android? Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, audio-recording, microphone, mediarecorder

I am investigating the possibilities of selecting the audio source/microphone for recordings being done on the mobile device. Ideally these can be selected independently from the audio output.
A use case would be to play audio to wired headphones, while simultaneously recording audio from the device-internal microphone.

A comparable iOS case would be [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiosession/capturing_stereo_audio_from_built-in_microphones).

I believe on Android this might be achievable via `setAudioSource()` on [MediaRecorder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder). An alternative might be `setPreferredDevice()` with [AudioRecord](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord).
However, I am not sure this is the right path...

Does anybody have experience in achieving this on Android or Flutter, respectively?

Thanks!

Comment: You manage to come up with a solution to this?

Comment: For Android not yet, unfortunately.

Comment: Any news for android?